# How do I change the group_id of a Table from being an ID of the primary user to being the Username of the primary user SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a group_id field in a table that holds the id of for the group and is associate with the primary member of that group. So any of the records that has a group_id value of 1 for instance belongs to group 1 and the record with the id of 1 is primary user). I am trying to update all records in the table by changing the value of the group_id from the id of the primary user to being the username of the primary user. I don't use strict SQL very often, but need to know how to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated.
i.e.:

```
ID    username        group_id
1     bobdabuilder    1
2     cb49210         1
3     the_man         1
```

I need to change it so something like:

```
ID    username        group_id
1     bobdabuilder    bobdabuilder 
2     cb49210         bobdabuilder 
3     the_man         bobdabuilder
```

Comment: Please post sample data and expected output.

Comment: Included an example of what I need to do

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.username,
    s.username AS group
FROM sometable u
INNER JOIN sometable s
    ON s.id = u.group_id
ORDER BY u.id ASC
```

The above join clause should work as expected/required.

---

The `UPDATE` query would be written along the same lines:

```
UPDATE sometable a
INNER JOIN sometable b
    ON a.group_id = b.id
SET a.group_id = b.username
```

Comment: I am trying to change the data in the same table, so can I use this code when it is the same table or do I have to make a temporary copy of the table to change the data?

Comment: @Battousai That is a very bad DB design idea. Keep the group_id as integer/pointer to the ID of actual user. It takes less HDD space, and looking up using a join is fast (since MySQL already has a copy of the table in memory)

Comment: The issue is that I have created a new site. On the old site the additional group members are added after the primary user, so it is easy to grab the id and add it as the group_id for the other group members, but with the new site, primary users can add themselves as well as additional users simultaneously and since there isn't a record for the primary user yet, it is difficult to add the users id  as the group_id for the additional members of that group. To my understanding, I am unable to grab the would be id of the primary user and add that as the group_id.

Comment: In that case, you should split the tables. One stores the group leaders/primary only. Another stores general members. The second table would also contain the primary user's name, attached to their own ID from the leaders table. So, a leader may have id `x` in users table, but `y` in leaders table. The row in users table would be `x, name, y` and in leaders table would be `y, name` only. The name column of leaders table would be UNIQUE, to avoid creating duplicates.

Comment: I am confused... can you clarify this process? I.E. Who gets added to where and in what order? Primary user to both tables first? does it matter the order?

Comment: @Battousai The order will not matter. Read about table normalisation (1NF, 2NF, BCNF etc.) on wikipedia. That should help you out a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95998/discussion-between-battousai-and-hjpotter92).